# How to create voice recognition on gae site?

Tags: android, iphone, google-app-engine, voice-recognition

Here is the code to recognize flac file.
But how can I record that with user's browser? (my site is for android and iphone)

```
class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):  
def post(self):
    destinationURL = "http://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize?xjerr=1&client=chromium&lang=en-US"
    result = urlfetch.fetch(url=destinationURL, payload= self.request.body, method=urlfetch.POST, headers={'Content-Type': 'audio/x-flac; rate=16000'})  
    self.response.out.write(result.content)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browser-side voice recording can only be done with java applets, which neither iPhone nor Android supports.

There is a possibility to record voice with Flash and RTMP server, but Flash only runs on (some) Android phones and RTMP servers do not run on GAE (since they require sockets).

The only way to make this work is to forget the browser and create native apps that record audio and upload it to GAE server via HTTP.

Comment: What is about HTML5 audio features? Is it supported by iPhone and Android browsers?

Comment: AFAIK HTML5 Media Capture is not yet supported on iPhone or Android.

Comment: Your first sentence contradicts your second. :)

Comment: Also, there's no reason to upload to App Engine in the case of a native app (which is a good idea) - just upload straight to the recognition service instead.